# How to Wait for Listener to Complete Before Returning

Tags: c#

I want to wait for my listener to complete before returning the containing function.

Consider this function:

```
public static Users GetUser(string sUserID)
    {
        Users oUser = null;

        var listener = new UserEventHelper((sender, e) =>
        {
            if ((e as UserArgs).Value != null)
            {
                oUser = (e as UserArgs).Value;
            }
        });
        oRoot.Child("users").OrderByKey().EqualTo(sUserID).AddListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);

        return oUser;
    }
```

Other Classes:

```
class UserEventHelper : Java.Lang.Object, IValueEventListener
{
    EventHandler OnChange;

    public UserEventHelper(EventHandler OnChange)
    {
        this.OnChange = OnChange;
    }

    public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        if (OnChange != null && snapshot.Value != null)
        {
            Users oUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(snapshot.Value.ToString());
            OnChange.Invoke(this, new UserArgs(oUser));
        }
        else
        {
            OnChange.Invoke(this, new UserArgs(null));
        }
    }
}

public class UserArgs : EventArgs
{
    public UserArgs(Users value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public Users Value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I structure my code in such a way that I know the user value is set from inside the listener before I return from the function? Note: There could be other issues with the code but I would like to focus on this conceptual question.

Comment: UserEventHelper is the _notifier_,  it is the source of the event, it is not the _listener_. From the naming of the variables, I think you are taking it as the listener.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. My naming is not very clear. It doesn't change much in the way of my question though. I can't return from inside the delegate, but it's not guaranteed to be called before the return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot really think of a way to return an object from the GetUser method, this method just *subscribes* to an event and provides an action to be taken when the event is fired, and there is no guarantee *when* the event will be fired.

So it should not be called **GetUser**, since it cannot return a user object. Besides, what do you expect the method to return when the event is fired multiple times? Just take the first one and discard the others?

The solution is, instead of trying to return a user object to the *caller*, just doing whatever you want on the user object just inside the action (the listener) you provided when you subscribing to the event.

```
var listener = new UserEventHelper((sender, e) =>
    {
        if ((e as UserArgs).Value != null)
        {
            oUser = (e as UserArgs).Value;
            //you have a user object now, just do your work here! 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of having all of my subsequent logic inside that if statement. I was just trying to clean up the code because I am going to be using logic like that quite often. I will mark this as the answer. Thanks.